How to manage security between APP -> BACKEND / Keycloak, Spring boot, ionic
I have a system that consists of:
A backend in Spring Boot,
A CRUD dashboard (React),
A mobile app (Ionic).
Security is delegated to Keycloak.
The security of my CRUDs is protected since I have users and passwords for the dashboard with their roles, and these are implemented in Spring Boot.
From my backend, I have created an auth section to properly store the secrets so they are not exposed to the client. For example, the dashboard login goes against my backend, and my backend interacts with Keycloak.
The question comes in how to implement it in the app since I want "public" endpoints but, despite being "public," they should only be accessible by the app.
The challenge is that my app does not handle users, so I don't have users and passwords.
I can't think of what type of client to create in Keycloak or how to handle this situation.
I've tried to implement a client with authentication type grant_type = client_credentials and have the app perform logins underneath, but this creates a problem/fear for me:
Anyone who has access to the app's login endpoint will be able to impersonate the app since it doesn't require a username and password.

Why don't mobile app users authenticate like those of the React dashboard do?

It is a project requirement that the app does not have users. It only uses 3 GET endpoints, and the table is maintained by the admin who does have a user in the dashboard

I'm not sure I understood. You don't want to know who is using the app, but what the app displays depends on who is using the app?

No, the app is free. It is an app for viewing events at city bars. The dashboard is only for the admin to manage these events, such as creating, deleting, updating them, etc., among other functionalities. However, the app itself is solely for viewing events, so users are not needed.
